# Colpits Oscillator

Tags: oscillator

I am trying to generate sine wave via Colpits oscillator method as described above. But I am unable to generate any. The output is at constant 5V. The condition for starting the oscillation is $$g_m = 0.5, r_o=14k\Omega, g_mr_o > 1$$. Which is met.

Still I could not get the sine wave as expected. Can someone be kind enough to drop couple of clues here, I am breaking my head over this for last one day! I am a newbie.

**____________________________**

[image]

Comment: Why are the two circuits different. My eyes are old and fading but even I can see they are different. Voting to close.

Comment: removed the first circuit.

Comment: You still have a link to one circuit and you should make it clear to Russell that you are altering the question to remove redundant information and that this may invalidate his answer. Accuracy is one of the major disciplines to learn when involving yourself in EE.

Comment: @Andyaka Agree. Comment only: The change did not just remove redundant information but altered the actual circuit and one component type and several component values.

Comment: @Andyaka Your vote to close is in violation of site guidelines. FWIW.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I would have thought that anyone able to inspect the names of close-voters would have to be a site moderator and that would make their announcement of voters prior to actual closure certainly wrong at many levels. Does this mean you are a site moderator Russell or are you just taking a guess?

Comment: @Andyaka I'm utterly awesome (except when I'm utterly pathetic) [YMMV]. but, in this case, I'm just taking you at your word, and assuming that you are a man of action :-). Apart from Occam's advice, assuming that there are not two Andy aka's in the system (I could have clicked the name to be 100% certain) then I assume that your statement above -  "... My eyes are old and fading but even I can see they are different. Voting to close." Meant that you were voting to close, and thus that the sole registered close vote was yours. I do, and did, realise that I may be wrong. Occam said "Go for it."

Comment: @RussellMcMahon nicely put. I'm an idiot!!!

Comment: @Andyaka I resemble that :-). More often than I'd wish to :-). Looks like a case of scrupulous observation of [Matthew 6:3b](http://biblehub.com/matthew/6-3.htm)* and exercise of ambidextrous typing skills. | *But not, it seems, of the spirit of 6:3a. [ :-) ]

Comment: @RussellMcMahon ah... going all biblical on me eh? 'Bout time you went to bed methinketh.

Comment: @Andyaka Apposite, methought. Yea, verily, methinketh! Well, if 'tis not thy right and left hand that knoweth not what the other doeth, then praps happly tis thy right and left brains that communicateth not? While indeed time in bed I oft times crave more than achieve, it may be that thou too wouldest find that more sleeping and less methinking on thy part may be in order :-).

Comment: Either you have NOT made all the changes suggested OR the circuit is incorrect. | The RFC or resistor feed should be to the collector end of the tank - make it so. It may or may not matter. Do it anyway. | R2 R3 are wrong - maybe swapped or ??? - Vbase DC is now VERY high,  | Can you use higher Vcc IF using as resistor feed? - as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

**Added:**

R2 / R5 divider values are very very very low so base is very "stiff" wrt feedback. Are those REALLY the values used? -> 250 Ohms and 88 Ohms? -
If so increase them VERY substantially say 33k & 10k - about the same DC bias but gives feedback a chance given L & C values used.

**______________________________**

You edited the circuit and the edited version has two substantial differences.

[image]

Were you using both circuits or only the second?

As shown the output CANNOT be at 5V if the transistor is working so you must not be doing what you show here.

Vout is either 0V AC (due to the capacitor)
OR the collector shows an oscillation
OR the collector is at about 4.4V DC
BECAUSE Vb ~= 1.25VDC so Ve ~= 0.65 Vdc So Vr1 ~= Vr4 so Vc must be droped by Ic = Ie in R4
SO you are not doing what you say or saying what is really happening.

R4 should feed the collector end of L1 although the difference should be small. This is what your prior diagram showed so why has it changed?
Did you use an RFC or only a resistor for R4?
Did you change the base bias R's as shown?

Please advise re the inconsistencies mentioned above if you want more input.

**_______________________________**

There are [**107 Stack Exchange Colpitts Oscillator questions here**](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=colpitts+oscillator) -  a look  at a selection of these may help.

Comment: The second one, I am using.

"Did you use an RFC or only a resistor for R4?" - I tried both, but now the resistor only.

Comment: Have you moved R4 to other end of L1? What is Vc? What is Ve? Have you tried this in real life and/or simulation?

Comment: Yes I tried in real life, not working either in hardware or simulation. Vc = 4.366V, Vb=1.3V, Ve=610mV, Ic = 6.338mA.

Comment: @niki_t1 C5 should NOT be polarised / electrolytic. C1 probably not. | Please answer ALL questions per pass if feasible. Did you move R4 to other end of L?. || What expected freq. Wht so bu=ig values for C5 & C1 ?  || AHA maybe - see next comment. ->

Comment: In hardware C5 and C1 are polarised, but it should not matter in simulation though. Yes I moved R4 to the other end of L1. Expected frequency is 5Mhz.

Comment: @niki_t1  R2 R5 divider values are very very very low so base is very "stiff" wrt feedback. Are those REALLY tyhe values used? -> 250 Ohms and 88 Ohms? - If so increase them VERY substantially say 33k & 10k - about the same DC bias but gioves feedback a chance given L & C values used.

Comment: I just did in simulation, but still no oscillation!! one thing though, my poles are way far in right half plane, would that be a problem?

Comment: @niki_t1  Poles in RHP is a requirement for oscillation. What's not to like ? :-). | What values now for R2 R5. | Try reducing C5 to something sane. MAY be influencing startup by providing close to a DC clamp due to immensely low impedance. .

Comment: @niki_t1 Did you try making C5 **MUCH** smaller. Say < to << 1 uF

Comment: yes I did ... but did not work. I believe I need RFC (very high value inductor) in place of R4. But I don't have one with me. So I am going to try it with an Op-Amp where I don't need RFC. What do you think?

Comment: @niki_t1 Can you post your now current circuit? | R4 should now be connected to collector. Bias resistors are now what value?. C5 is what value. C1 is what value? C5 IS NON POLAR. |IF you have a hihgher Vdc avalable you can use higher R4. At present you say Ic =~ 6 mA. So 1k Would drop 6V . So 20V supply would allow R4 ~= 2.5K . R2 needs to be larger to keep Vb the same. 12v or more may help.

Comment: Still not working. Updated the new circuit in the question itself. increased bias resistances. Ic=3mA now. I still think I don't have large enough RFC for the circuit to work, as there is not enough insulation from power supply for the circuit to work. What do you think. I am going to try with a High-Speed Op-Amp now @russellmcmahon